# how to calculate the duration of year when user entered the date in textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to display the duration?When the dated is entered in textbox,in next field the total number of years(duration).
Example:
if user entered 09/11/2015.it should be displayed as 0.5 as value,by comparing to today's date.
`Now i use the script script

```js
function cal()
{
   obj = document.getElementById("Date");
        if (obj != null) {
            if (obj.value != "") {
                var year = obj.value.split("/")[2];
                var today = new Date();
                if (year > today.getFullYear()) {
                    alert("Invalid Year");
                    document.getElementById("Date").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("year").value = "";
                }
                else {
               
         document .getElementById("year").value = today.getFullYear() - year;
               } }
            }
}
```

`

Comment: what have you been tried so far??

Comment: what _formula_ or _logic_ are you trying to apply here to get `0.5` when user enter the date as mentioned in ur question. Kindly explain more about your requirement.

Comment: When user entered the date in textbox,I want to display the total number of years.if the date is between 6months from the current date the value should be 0.5,if the date is between 1year then value as 1,then next six months 1.5, and so on..

Comment: guzzs canyou all say some more examples please its urgent..

Answer (score 0):

```js
function aa(){
var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var firstDate = new Date(2016,04,12);
var secondDate = new Date(2016,04,25);

var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));

alert(diffDays+" Day(s)");
//document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=diffDays;

}
```

```html
<button onClick="aa()">
Click
</button>
```